# How can i allow the thread which is an implementation of interface to communicate with the JWindow objects?

Tags: java, oop, swing, interface, interface-implementation

How can i get the **Network counter value** to include in my **Main JButton goal**? I was doing something like this:

**Main.java:**

```
package demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class Main extends JWindow
{
    private static JButton goal = new JButton("old");
    private static JWindow j;
    private static Process application;

    public Main()
    {   
       this.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
       this.setVisible(true);
       this.add(goal,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        j = new Main();
        j.setVisible(true);

        try {
            application = new Process();
            application.start();
            // <<<<< Here i want to see the counter, from network.java >>>>>
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Process.java

```
package demo;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Process extends Thread 
{
  public Network alert;          
  public Vector listenerList;
  private boolean running;

  public Process() throws Exception
  {
    listenerList = new Vector();
    alert = new Network(); 
    addNetworkListener(alert);

    this.running = true;
  }

  public void addNetworkListener(Network ls)
  {
    listenerList.addElement(ls);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("Starting..");  
    try {
      while(running)
      {
        System.out.println("running...");
        FireEvent();
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //
    }
  }

  private void FireEvent()
  {
     //System.exit(0);
     alert.Registered();
  }
}
```

Network.java

```
package demo;

public class Network implements NetworkListener 
{    
    public int  counter = 0 ;
    public void Registered() 
    {
        System.out.println("network: " + counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter>40) System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

NetworkListener.java

```
package demo;

public interface NetworkListener 
{
    public void Registered();
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but makes it hard to read: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: ok leared and modified. Next?

Comment: not quite (should be registered) - but see the effort :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quite know *how* exactly you want to see the counter, assuming you want to update some component showing the counter.

Basically, you'll need a setup which ultimately leads to notifying about a change of the counter *on the EDT* Then your ui listens to that change and updates the component as appropriate. F.i.

```
public class Network implements NetworkListener 
{    
    public int  counter = 0 ;
    public void registered() 
    {
        System.out.println("network: " + counter);
        counter++;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 fireCounterChanged( ... );
             }
        });
        if (counter>40) System.exit(0);
    }

    public void addChangeListener(...) {
         ....
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(...) {
         ....
    }
    private void fireCounterChanged(...) {
        // notify all listeners
    }  

}

// usage
ChangeListener l = new ChangeListener() {
       public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
           button.setText("counter: " + ((NetWork) e.getSource()).counter;
       }
};
```

Comment: This clear my concept really. But however i am very confused where did you find the ChangeListener() class? Did you anyhow mean NetworkListener() ?

Comment: no, ChangeListener is a listener type in Swing - you can use whichever you want, just make sure notification happens on the EDT.